# using external JUL "logging.properties" in spring boot logging

Tags: java, spring-boot, java.util.logging

I have an legacy osgi application and embedded spring boot as a bundle in that.

The legacy app uses logging.properties(JUL) as logging system. When spring boot bundle starts, LogBack takes control of logging and logging.properties doesn't work anymore.

I tried with

```
 org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem=org.springframework.boot.logging.java.JavaLoggingSystem 

 logging.config=/xxx/yyy/zzz/logging.properties
```

and not work

Can I directly use the defined logging.properties in spring boot? And if yes, How?

Comment: Have you checked out the docs? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging

Answer (score 1):

remove default logback and add necessary dependency seems work

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```